# Empty string as a output field seperator for Cut

Tags: linux, cut

How can I use cut with `--output-delimiter=""`? I want to join two columns using cut.

I tried the following command. However `cat -v` shows that there are non printable characters. Specifically "`^@`". Any suggestions to how can I overcome this?

```
cut -d, -f 3,6 --output-delimiter=""  file1.csv | cat -v
```

This is the content of my file

011,IBM,Palmisano,t,t,t
012,INTC,Otellini,t,t,t
013,SAP,Snabe,t,t,t
014,VMW,Maritz,t,t,t
015,ORCL,Ellison,t,t,t
017,RHT,Whitehurst,t,t,t

When i run my command I'm seeing 
Palmisano^@t
Otellini^@t
Snabe^@t
Maritz^@t
Ellison^@t
Whitehurst^@t

Expected output: Basically I want to exclude ^@ in the output

Palmisanot
Otellinit
Snabet
Maritzt
Ellisont
Whitehurstt

Thank you.

Comment: post any examples of expected output

Comment: @mohanraj:  I have updated my question with the expected and current output

Comment: I don't have any non printable in the original file.  I have pasted a sample of rows in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output delimiter is not an empty string, but probably the `NULL` character. You might want to try

```
cut -d, -f 3,6 --output-delimiter=$'\00' file1.csv
```

(Assuming your shell supports `$'...'`-quoting; `bash` and `zsh` are fine here, not sure about others).

*edit:*

`cut` apparently puts the `NULL` character if the output separator is set to the empty string. I do not see a way around it.

If `awk` is an acceptable solution, this will do the trick:

```
awk -F, '{print $3 $6}' file*
```

If you want to be more verbose and explicit:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","; OFS=""}; {print $3,$6}' file*
```

`FS=","` sets the field separator to `,`.
`OFS=""` sets the Output Field Separator to the empty string.

Comment: cat -v still shows the non-printable characters.  Is this because cut doesnt accept null delimiter for output ?

Comment: Thanks. I was working my way around using awk as well. But for a sec thought I coulld achieve this only using cut.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to cut by **fields** but instead by **characters** or perhaps **bytes**.  See the description of `-c` and/or `-b` in the man page, instead of using `-f`.

Comment: I cannot use characters as my fields are not fixed length

Comment: Sorry, I misread "output delimiter" as "input delimiter".  As for removing the NULs, you could pipe your results through `tr -d '\0'` - does that work for you?